What is the time-averaged gravitational wave power of the Milky Way
I would like to learn, if possible, an estimate of the total time-averaged power of gravitational wave emission at frequencies below GHz by the Milky Way. For example the value might be something like
$$
(\mbox{number of mergers per unit time}) \times (\mbox{mean energy emitted per merger})
+ (\mbox{number of binaries with long-lasting orbits}) \times (\mbox{mean power per binary})
$$
I tried to extract an estimate from the following figure (from "Upper Limits on the Stochastic Gravitational-Wave Background from
Advanced LIGO’s First Observing Run", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02029)

It looks like most of the energy is from BBH and BNS so I did a rough integral of the shown curves. However I'm not sure if I am doing it right. That integral gave an energy density about $2 \times 10^{-9}\,\rho_{\rm crit}$, but I'm not sure if I did that right, and I'm not sure how to convert it into a "total power per galaxy". (Here $\rho_{\rm crit} = 3 c^2 H_0^2/8\pi G$, the cosmological critical energy density).

Over what time scale are you willing to average? Mergers are very rare, and if averaging over a century the number of mergers is typically zero. Of course, if you average over a long enough time mergers will contribute (and because of their immense intensity contribute significantly). On the scale of millions of years, you also need to account for EMRIs into sagitarius A*. If you wait even longer, you will have to account for the merger of the Milky Way with Andromeda and the potential merger of the supermassive black holes at their centers.

Thanks for this comment which goes some way to answering. I think a good answer would start with an average without mergers, and then bring in the mergers and EMRI.
